# What do I need to know before applying for a junior developer position?

Tags: web-frontend

I'm looking for advice on where to go from here...

So some background, I've been teaching mathematics for 7 years and have a masters in math education, and I've been studying a fair amount of web development in hopes of transitioning to a career in web development.

So far, I have been most interested in front end technologies.  I've done well learning and building simple projects with html, css, bootstrap, wordpress, javascript, jquery, and angular.

I've done some *very simple* work/tutorials with nodejs, ruby, and python.  I've completed a simple tutorial on SQL queries and joins.

I've been talking with a few friends in the development world, and I just am not sure where to go from here.  One friend is in enterprise software and security and thinks I should know a lot about the back end and databases as well as a fair amount of knowledge of programming conceptual knowledge.  My other friend has worked in various positions in web development and suggests I learn a lot about Angular, and get limited experience with back end dev for now.  He also suggests I practice specific often-asked questions for interviews.

I really like the front end tech I've worked with, but how much do I need to know about back end work to be ready to apply for a junior front end position?  How much experience do I need working with databases? What topics should I familiarize myself with to be prepared for technical interviews?

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6488/ Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz at Workplace such questions are [explicitly off-topic](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695/168) (*"what skills should I learn?"*). Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with

Answer (score 0):

If you want to focus purely on front end development work there is little need to know a great deal about back end stuff. If you are proficient in angular, javascript, html and css then you are on course. I would suggest taking a couple of interviews and seeing what they ask you that you feel weak on, and taking it from there.

There comes a point when you have to just "go for it". The best learning is done in the dev projects.